# how to hide 'hour' in xAxis

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart with xAxis as follows:

```
                            'xAxis' : {
                          'type' : 'datetime',
                          'labels' : {
                            'rotation' : -90,
                            'align' : 'right',
                            'y' : 1
                          },
                          'dateTimeLabelFormats' : {
                            'day' : '%e-%b',
                            'week' : '%e-%b',
                            'month' : '%b-%y'
                          }
                        }
```

But it shows not only day/month but also hours. Is there a way to hide hours here?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consider `minTickInterval` to set it to one day - otherwise Highcharts will calculate interval, and set it for example to a half day (like you have in your case). If there wouldn't be 12:00 labels, then you will receive doubled labels. Of course other answer will resolve issue with displaying `12:00`, but wouldn't prevent displaying extra labels.

Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minTickInterval

Answer (score 0):

What format do you want it in? You can put it in the format of 'day' of 'month' by doing something like this.

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: '%e of %b'
        }
    },
```

Comment: Also, you may be getting the hours on your x-axis because your point interval is too frequent (i.e. between days) try
`pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // this equals one day`

Comment: you don't want to change the point interval for the sake of the labeling - the pointIntverval defines at what interval the data occurs.  The tickInterval is what you need to change to affect the labeling.

Comment: @Sualkcin my question is how to hide 'hour'. I already use that format in day and month, but I still get hour like above chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use label [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) and [highcharts.dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat%28%29)